# Why is using inject/reduce more efficient than using map.with_index when working with large collections (in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, performance, big-o

I was working on a [Codewar problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ce399e0047a45001c853c2b) and the method I came up with worked with small arrays, but didn't work for very large arrays.

The solution provided used the `inject` method, which I assume is more efficient than the combination of `map` and `with_index` I had.

However, I'm not sure I understand why the `inject` method is more efficient than looping. Could someone please shine some light on this?

The problem was the following: 
Given an array, return an array where each element is the sum of the array's subparts.

Example: `array = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]`

I'm summing every array element while iterating on the array (so the array gets smaller and smaller):

```rb
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10] => 20
[1, 3, 6, 10] => 20
[3, 6, 10] => 19
[6, 10] => 16
[10] => 10
[] => 0
```

Hence the method would return here: `[20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]`

My solution (which works for small arrays but is too inefficient for large arrays):

```rb
def parts_sums(ls)
  (ls + [0]).map.with_index { |_, i| ls[i..-1].sum }
end
```

The provided solution:

```rb
def parts_sums(ls)
  ls.reduce([ls.sum]) { |sums, x| sums << sums.last - x }
end
```

By browsing the Codewars comment section, I've understood that this performance difference is linked to the Big O notation. However, every resource I found on this topic is way beyond my mathematical and algorithm understanding.

I've also looked at the Ruby doc but I don't understand C enough to be able to read the implementation of those methods.

Could someone please explain in quite simple terms why `inject`/`reduce` is more efficient than `map.with_index` in this situation?

Comment: It might help to look at the intermediate values created by your `parts_sums` implementation.

Comment: I don't think `inject` is causing the difference. The provided code sums once and does one subtraction per item. Your code does a lot more summing.

Comment: The number of sums done with the `map` solution is approximately `(N^2 + N) / 2`, if I calculated correctly. The number of sums (or subtractions + sums) in the `reduce` solution is `2*N`. Therefore one solution has polynomial complexity  O(N^2), and the other has linear complexity O(N). Big difference.

Comment: @Casper O(N^2) is _polynomial_ time. O(2^N) would be exponential

Comment: It is not that the use of `inject` is more efficient than looping. It is that one algorithm is more efficient than another, as explained by @Alexkei in his answer. There are ways to achieve efficiency comparable to the `reduce` solution that do not use `reduce`. In future you may wish to hold off selecting an answer (I'm referring to your original choice) for at least a couple of hours. Not only can quick selections discourage the posting of other answers, but, as here, the selected answer may be shown to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s start with `reduce` version.

```
ls.reduce([ls.sum]) { |sums, x| sums << sums.last - x }
```

It sums an array once (on step zero,) and then it subtracts two integers on each subsequent iteration.

---

Your solution *sums* the tail of the array on each step. Summing requires the whole array traversal, that’s why it is quite inefficient on large arrays.